# How to write data sequentially based on a key into an other csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group by a column data on my dataset, Here is what I have tried till now.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(["sender"])
for key,item in grouped_df:
  a_group = grouped_df[["rcvTime","pos_x","pos_y","pos_z","spd_x","spd_y","spd_z","acl_x","acl_y","acl_z","hed_x","hed_y","hed_z"]].get_group(key)
  print(a_group, "\n")
```

the output for it is like the following:
for key=15

```
   rcvTime   pos_x    pos_y  pos_z  spd_x  spd_y  spd_z  acl_x  acl_y  acl_z  \
0   25207.0  136.07  1118.46    0.0   0.00   0.00    0.0   0.00   0.00    0.0   
1   25208.0  136.19  1117.14    0.0   0.22  -2.31    0.0   0.14  -1.48    0.0   
3   25209.0  136.69  1113.79    0.0   0.39  -4.18    0.0   0.15  -1.64    0.0   
5   25210.0  133.77  1108.01    0.0   0.58  -6.17    0.0   0.16  -1.76    0.0   
7   25211.0  134.37  1100.75    0.0   0.76  -8.14    0.0   0.18  -1.93    0.0
```

for key=22

```
rcvTime   pos_x   pos_y  pos_z  spd_x  spd_y  spd_z  acl_x  acl_y  acl_z  \
2   25208.81  152.66  904.56    0.0   0.06  -0.75    0.0   0.18  -2.43    0.0   
4   25209.81  152.98  902.59    0.0   0.22  -2.91    0.0   0.12  -1.68    0.0   
6   25210.81  153.25  898.68    0.0   0.37  -4.65    0.0   0.11  -1.35    0.0   
8   25211.81  153.82  893.00    0.0   0.65  -6.67    0.0   0.25  -2.54    0.0
```

for key=31

```
rcvTime   pos_x   pos_y  pos_z  spd_x  spd_y  spd_z  acl_x  acl_y  acl_z  \
25211.93  122.87  892.12    0.0   5.63   0.32    0.0  -1.57  -0.09    0.0   
25212.93  127.24  892.36    0.0   3.30   0.19    0.0  -1.52  -0.09    0.0   
25213.93  129.69  892.49    0.0   1.67   0.10    0.0  -1.54  -0.09    0.0   
25214.93  130.79  892.55    0.0   0.71   0.04    0.0  -0.50  -0.03    0.0
```

now what I need is for each key the data displays sequentially and add them to a new csv file for example for key=31 the data should be like the following:

```
rcvTime,pos_x,pos_y,pos_z,spd_x,spd_y,spd_z,acl_x,acl_y,acl_z,rcvTime,pos_x,pos_y,pos_z,spd_x,spd_y,spd_z,acl_x,acl_y,acl_z,rcvTime,pos_x,pos_y,pos_z,spd_x,spd_y,spd_z,acl_x,acl_y,acl_z
25211.93,122.87,892.12,0.0,5.63,0.32,0.0,-1.57,-0.09,25212.93,127.24,892.36,0.0,3.30,0.19,0.0,-1.52,-0.09,0.0,25213.93,129.69,892.49,0.0,1.67,0.10,0.0,-1.54,-0.09,0.0,....
```

And then for the next key it should writes into an other line the data for the next key in that csv file. I appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [4, 5, 6], "col2": [9, 8, 7]})
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df_temp = df.loc[idx:idx].reset_index(drop=True)
    df_new  = pd.concat([df_new, df_temp], axis=1)
df_new.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

and the output csv looks like this-

```
col1,col2,col1,col2,col1,col2
4,9,5,8,6,7
```